# Strange performance behavior on PostGIS PointField query

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, postgis, geodjango

**Django=** 1.10.4

**PostgreSQL=** 9.6.1

**POSTGIS=**"2.3.0 r15146" GEOS="3.5.0-CAPI-1.9.0 r4084" PROJ="Rel. 4.9.2, 08 September 2015" GDAL="GDAL 2.1.1, released 2 016/07/07" LIBXML="2.9.1" LIBJSON="0.12" RASTER

---

My User class

```
class User(AbstractUser, TimeStampedModel):
    """Custom user model.
    Attributes:
        avatar (file): user's avatar, cropped to fill 300x300 px
        location (point): latest known GEO coordinates of the user
        location_updated (datetime): latest time user updated coordinates
        notifications (dict): settings for notifications to user
        is_appuser (bool): if True user can access to apps
    """
    AVATAR_IMAGE_SIZE = (300, 300)
    avatar = imagekitmodels.ProcessedImageField(
        upload_to=upload_user_media_to,
        processors=[ResizeToFill(*AVATAR_IMAGE_SIZE)],
        format='PNG',
        options={'quality': 100},
        editable=True,
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )

    location = gis_models.PointField(default=Point(x=0, y=0, srid=4326),
                                     blank=True,
                                     srid=4326)
    location_updated = models.DateTimeField(null=True,
                                            blank=True,
                                            editable=False)
    notifications = HStoreField(null=True)
    is_appuser = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    # so authentication happens by email instead of username
    # and username becomes sort of nick
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    # Make sure to exclude email from required fields if authentication
    # is done by email
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'User'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Users'

    def get_conferences(self):
        """Get confrences where the user is attendee.

        Returns:
            QuerySet of conferences.

        """

        return Conference.objects.filter(attendees=self)
```

Now if I query the record with all fields, the performance of the query is **70ms**, as seen from screenshot 1. If I remove 'location' field from the query - the performance is **3ms** (see 2nd query in both screenshots)

[image: screenshot 1]

**Now with *location* field removed from the query**

---

[image: screenshot 2]

However, if I run the same query in PSQL (i.e. bypassing Django ORM layer), then there is NO difference of the query

```
staging=> \timing
Timing is on.
staging=> select id,location from users_user where id=20;
 id |                      location                      
----+----------------------------------------------------
 20 | 0101000020E61000009A9999999999F13F9A9999999999F13F
(1 row)

Time: 1.310 ms
staging=> select id from users_user where id=20;
 id 
----
 20
(1 row)

Time: 1.300 ms
staging=>
```

Comment: what are `all the fields` ?

Comment: User.objects.filter(id=1) - will return all fields fromt the class, including the location. If location is removed with User.objects.filter(id=1).values(columns) - the latency drops from 70ms for the query above to 3ms

Comment: again, what are those field? because if they are in the index but location isnt, then the query would be faster

Comment: Juan, index optimizer has no effect on fields in SELECT clause, only in WHERE clause. So yes, index on ID (PK) exists in DB and it's queried using that index. So all fields of User class but one (*location) drops the latency from 77ms to 3ms

Comment: You are wrong. if index contain the select field, db doesnt have to do a look up on the table to get the value.

Comment: Show me your `CREATE TABLE` with **all index**.

Comment: Just wonder, what app show you all those explain at the same time? but why you didnt filter to show only the relevant query.

Comment: Juan - I disagree, such approach (i.e. partition your data by indexing all projected fields needed from a query into index works well for dynamodb for example, which essentially result in a subset of a table including only the fields you want  but for this given query has no effect. The problem is not on SQL side, it's on Django ORM side. If I run the query with location or without the location field in pure psql console - I always get the same result equal to 1.2-2ms most.

Comment: Im not saying you did or should do it, I just need the info the discard scenarios.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136190/discussion-between-dmitrysemenov-and-juan-carlos-oropeza).